# Play Framework with Spring, @Transactional not working

Tags: spring, playframework

I'm using Play Framework (2.2.2) in combination with Spring (using this template: https://github.com/jamesward/play-java-spring).

If I annotate the Application Controller with `@Transactional` it's working fine:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@Transactional
public class Application {
  // ...
}
```

However, if I also extend from Play's Base Controller I get the following error:

```
[NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [controllers.Application] is defined]
```

Code:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
@Transactional
public class Application extends play.mvc.Controller{
    // ...
}
```

So for some reason the `@Transactional`Annotation combined with `extends play.mvc.Controller` leads to a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Using either `@Transactional` OR `extends play.mvc.Controller` (not both combined) and Spring can instantiate the controller bean just fine.

How can I make them both work together?

This is the full stackstrace:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [controllers.Application] is defined]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:293) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:399) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$applyOrElse$3.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library.jar:na]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$2.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:261) [play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [controllers.Application] is defined
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:296) ~[spring-beans.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1125) ~[spring-context.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at Global.getControllerInstance(Global.java:21) ~[na:na]
        at play.core.j.JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.getControllerInstance(JavaGlobalSettingsAdapter.scala:46) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.2.2]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
        at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(routes_routing.scala:57) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I posted a possible direction bellow, if not could you post the full stacktrace with all the caused by clauses? If it's too big can you post a link to pastebin.com. But the recommended best practive is to put `@Transactional` in the service layer and not the persistence or controller layer

Answer (score 0):

Actually the controller itself should not be transactional, as transactionality is a concern of the service layer and not the presentation/web layer or the repository layer.

There are several reasons for this, for example the controller layer might trigger several business transactions. It's possible to make a controller transactional but it's not recommended practice, if you move the `@Transactional` annotation from the controller to the `@Service` layer, it will surely work.

Comment: Yes this would be possible. 

However, if I for example have an entity with a (lazily loaded) OneToMany relation to another entity and in my controller I want to access this related entity I get an error "No Session" or similar if I do not use Transactional. Therefore I want to use Transactional inside the controller.